# jQuery: $('#id').find('> a')... finds what, exactly?

Tags: jquery, find

I'm sure someone will change my title, but I liked it while it lasted.

Anyway, what the Hector does this do (as my seven-year-old would say)?

```
$('#id').find('> a')...
```

BTW, I get that `$('#parent > .child')` is the same as `$('#parent').children('.child')` (as explained [here](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/)), not that I ever use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `> a` without a specified parent is actually deprecated syntax, since as you've discovered it has ambiguous semantics.  `.find('> a')` is actually equivalent to `.children('a')`.

From http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/

> Note: The `$("> elem", context)` selector will be deprecated in a future release. Its usage is thus discouraged in lieu of using alternative selectors.

[ Remembering that `$(sel, context)` is equivalent to `$(context).find(sel)` ]

Comment: You probably need to update your answer in light of the discussion below to show that it is equivalent to .children not .find :)

Comment: @Nick strictly the answer above is still 100% correct - `.find('> a')` is currently equivalent to `.children('a')`.  My comment in the deleted answer from Nelson was incorrect, though.  AIUI what they're planning to deprecate is _any_ use of a selector that starts `"> ..."`.

Comment: Yes, it is 100% correct as it stands, but I'm not sure it will be 100% clear to someone who stumbles upon it :)  I thought you might like to clarify the children/find distinction.

Answer (score 1):

`.find()` is usually used to select descendants many levels down, however, in your case, adding the `>` before the `a` limits the selection to children only (or first level only if your using CSS class in place of #id).

It is essentially the same as `$('#id > a')` or `$('#id').children('a')` but with an extra function call.

Your title is perfect, BTW :)

Comment: Yes, you're right :) I just discovered this through trial and error, and returned to note as much, namely that it is equivalent to `.children()` not `.find()`. Glad you liked the title :)

Answer (score 1):

While you are trying to find an element using below query

```
$("#master").find('> a')
```

then it will find all the first level anchor element inside the element which has attribute id = 'master'

And while you are trying to find an element using below query

```
$("#master").find('a')
```

then it will find all the anchor element inside the element which has attribute id = 'master' no matter it is at what level.

Comment: Yes, so I've discovered. Thanks :)